How to find where a property comes from for a given element
One of the html elements that I'm rendering on the screen is centered, however, I want it to be left aligned. I'm trying to figure out what's causing it to be center aligned. Can someone please help me find the root cause of what's causing it to be center aligned. How to I find the root cause in Chrome debug tools?

Can you share the code with us? At least a proof of concept to replicate the issue.

There are a number of ways to center align something with CSS, so without seeing the code I can't provide a full answer, but there are a few things that might help you figure it out.
Inspect the centered element in Chrome DevTools using the inspector (the dotted line box in the top left). Once the correct element is selected in the elements panel you should see the currently active styles in the right side panel. If you then switch the to the computed view for styles you should see a single list of everything that is applied to that element. Next to the filter input uncheck "Show All" and make sure "Group" is checked. That will sort styles into categories. What you are looking for will be in the "Layout" category at the top of the list.
Some common things to look for would be text-align:center; margin: 0 auto; or possibly display:absolute;left:0;right:0;. Also look at the immediate parent element for display: flex; with align-items: center; or justify-content: center;.
If that fails best to post your code here to get more specific help.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
